# Equals method in C#

Tags: asp.net

I'm writing a part of code snippet where in I need to check for equality of two strings. But in my case below the control always hits the else part even if the two strings are equal.

Below is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetLoginData data = new GetLoginData();
    LoginDataSet login = new LoginDataSet();

    string email = "abc@gmail.com";
    string password = "asdfghjkl";


   login = data.getLoginData(email, password);
   /* login is a LoginDataSet object reference which holds email and password 
   data retreived from DB.*/

   string email1 = login.email.ToString();
   string password1 = login.password.ToString();

   if (email.Equals(email1) && password.Equals(password1))
   {
      //Does not execute at all
       Label1.Text = "true";
   }
   else
       Label1.Text = "false";
}
```

And my LoginDataSet class is as below:

```
public class LoginDataSet
{
    public virtual String email
    {   set;  get;}

public virtual String password
{    set;  get; }
```

}

Please let me know what is the mistake. As far as I know String class already has overridden the Equals method so we can directly use it. 
Help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hit a breakpoint and check the values. Are you sure both are actually same?

Comment: Yeah im sure they are because both the passed and received data are the same. But even then i added a break point and can clearly say both are same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure they are the same? If one character is uppercase it won't match.

If you want to ignore the case sensitive use:

```
.Equals("", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
```

**Your code**

```
if (email.Equals(email1, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) && password.Equals(password1, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
{
   //Does not execute at all
   Label1.Text = "true";
}
else
{
   Label1.Text = "false";
}
```

**Update: Seperate if statement**

```
if (email.Equals(email1, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
{
   Label1.Text = "true email";
}
else
{
   Label1.Text = "false email";
}

if (password.Equals(password1, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
{
   Label1.Text = "true password";
}
else
{
   Label1.Text = "false password";
}
```

What is this result?

**Removing whitespaces in front and end**

```
string email = Control.Text.Trim();
```

Comment: can you show us a copy of the exact values out of the db?

Comment: Everyone here was right. Data is wrong. Actually email is correct but password is incorrect. Actually password contains blank spaces in between i.e instead of "asdfghjkl" it is retreived as "asdfghjkl     " but I'm not getting why?

Comment: When you store values in your db try adding the `Trim()` function. This will remove all whitespaces in front and end of your string.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike Java, In C#, you don't need to use the `equals` method for strings. You can do:

```
password == password1
```

So, your `if` statement will become:

```
if (email == email1 && password == password1)
```

`equals` method should also work. So make sure your strings are actually equals (considering spaces at the end of them, padding, trimming, casing, encoding).

Comment: I tried the "==" even but result is same. It still hits the else part

Comment: Did you debug it? Are you sure the values are the same?

Comment: `==` actually ends up executing `String.Equals` on Strings.

Comment: Yes I checked them. they are same. Actually I'm fetching email and password if and only if the passed email and password matches to that of DB.

Comment: I think the simple facts here, as far as I can tell, is that your code is correct and should work.  The values must be different in some way.

Comment: @Dean.DePue Actually im retreiving data from DB table using the same email and password like select email and password from DBTable where email = 'abc@gmail.com' and password = 'asdfghjkl'. If both were not same then DB would not give the data in the first place.

Comment: So then why the additional test??

Answer (score 0):

`Equals` must work. Please check the values by `debugging`.

Also Try with following:

```
if (email == email1 && password == password1)
{
    //Does not execute at all
    Label1.Text = "true";
}
```

Comment: I tried debugging. Even I'm amazed as to why Equals is not working as expected. Sure a error on my side but not able to trace it